# How can i write this as a while loop? PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $number = mt_rand(1, 100);
    if ($number %2== 0) {
        $result = 'even';
    } else {
        $result = 'odd';
    }
    echo $number.' '.'('.$result.')'.'<br>';
}?>
```

I want to write it in a while loop form
this is as far as i have gotten. It just prints one random number and nothing else. I am using phpStorm and edge browser on PHP8.1.

```
<?php

$i=0;
while ($i<10) {
  if ($number=mt_rand(1,100)) {
    $result = 'even';
  } else {
    $result = 'odd';
  }
  $i++;
  echo $number.' '.'('.$result.')'.'<br>';
}
    
?>
```

Comment: The `while` version never uses `% 2` to check if it's even or odd.

Comment: I tried your script. It printed 10 different numbers, and said they were all even.

Comment: put $number=mt_rand(1,100) before the if, and use if($number %2== 0) also in the "while" version. You are not checking correctly if it's even or odd. Also, use phponline for those type of small-tests: https://onlinephp.io/c/3826a it correctly prints 10 times, but not checking even/odd

Comment: The `while` is fine, the problem is the `if` statement.

Comment: The code that was inside your original `for` loop does not need to change _at all_. All you need to do is add the `$i=0;`, change the `for(...)` to `while(...)`, and add `$i++` to the end. All of which you did correctly, but you also modified and broke the code that you had _inside_ of the loop.

Comment: 1 liner https://3v4l.org/Pj87l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason that the code is not working is that you are assigning the `$number = mt_rand(1,100)` inside the `if()` condition.

So everytime you execute if then it will not compare but it'll keep assigning the `$number` variable. I have separated the assignment and comparison logic.

Try This:

```
<?php

    $i=0;
    while ($i<10) {
        $number = mt_rand(1,100);
        if ($number % 2 == 0) {
            $result = 'even';
        } else {
            $result = 'odd';
        }
        $i++;
        echo $number.' '.'('.$result.')'.'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase  Done. Updated the explanation.

Comment: Thank you I marked your answer as solved!